# Dynamically naming a txt file

Tags: java, file

In my project I have to create files named with the "name" of a "cliente".

I've created a class Palabra (word), which has a char array and a number indicating the length of the word.

I've also created a class Cliente (client), which contains Palabras and arrays of Palabras indicating information about the client. The name of the client is a palabra array, for example.

I need to create as many txt files as clients I have, where each txt is named with the name of each client.

I've tried doing it like this, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
   for(int j=0; j<contarClientes(); j++){
        for(int i=0; clientes[j].nombre[i]!=null; i++){

            String nombreCliente=(clientes[j].nombre[i].convertirPalabraEnString());

            String nombreFichero=(clientes[j].nombre[i].convertirPalabraEnString()+".txt");
            FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(nombreFichero, false);
        }
   }
```

contarClientes() is an int that tells me how many Clientes I have
convertirPalabraEnString() converts a Palabra into a String

Comment: is there any reason you use char array and array of char array instead of a String?

Comment: Its a requisite of the task

Comment: What doesn't work? Are you receiving an error message? Is the file created with a different name?

Comment: its creating a txt file for each palabra. I need it to generate a file for each palabra array, where the name of the file is the whole palabra array.

Comment: You want to append all the palabras together in the filename?

Comment: Yes, separated by a blank space. For example, if the first client name is "John Smith" i'll have palabra array formed by the two palabras John and Smith. I want it to generate a txt file called "John Smith.txt"

Comment: @bohitargep - you may want to override the `Palabra.toString()` method as opposed to creating a new method with the same intended behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, what about this:

```
for (int j = 0; j < clientes.length; ++j) {
  String nombreFichero = new String();
  for (int i = 0; i < clientes[j].nombre.length && clientes[j].nombre[i] != null; ++i) {
    String nombreCliente = clientes[j].nombre[i].convertirPalabraEnString();
    nombreFichero += (nombreCliente + " ");
  }

  FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(nombreFichero.trim() + ".txt", false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To append all the parts in the 'nombre' array to the file name you need to move the write operation to the outer loop:

```
 for(int j=0; j<contarClientes(); j++){
    String nombreFichero = "";
    for(int i=0; clientes[j].nombre[i]!=null; i++){

        String nombreCliente=(clientes[j].nombre[i].convertirPalabraEnString());

        nombreFichero+=nombreCliente

    }
nombreFichero += ".txt";
 FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(nombreFichero, false);
}
```